# Removing splash screen in ionic 2 app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic 2 app and the default seems to be for the splash screen to fade/overlay into the opening page which looks really horrible so I would like to remove/hide the splash screen when the opening page loads. Is this possible?

I have tried putting:

```js
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

in the app.js constructor but this just makes the app hang at a blank page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`navigator.splashscreen.hide()` will indeed hide the splash-screen but it should be called only after the [device is ready](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/cordova/events/events.html#deviceready):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}
```

For ionic you could also use [Platform.ready()](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#ready) instead of `deviceready`, it will return a promise when native functionality can be called

```
constructor(public plt: Platform) {
    this.plt.ready().then((readySource) => {
      navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    });
}
```

Comment: Does it matter where in my ionic 2 app I add the document.addEventListener?

Comment: usually in the app.js file

Comment: can you tell me how can I handle this on Ionic2? B'cos it is using TS no?

Comment: @Sampath i am sorry but i was really busy lately, did you find the answer yet?

Answer (score 0):

on ionic 2 on app.js you can call the method ionViewLoaded